# Why String objects immutable in Java?

Tags: string, oop, object

I'm new to java programming.  And I don't understand why string objects are immutable in java.

```
String a = "Vehicle";
```

Comment: Do you want to say that though `String` objects are immutable how can we achieve `String a = "Vehicle"; a = "New " + a;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Because java uses the concept of **string literal**. Suppose there are five reference variables, all refers to one object `"Vehicle"`.If one reference variable changes the value of the object, it will be affected to all the reference variables. That is why string objects are immutable in java.

Comment: Well, that's *one* reason. It would be feasible for there to be "read-only" strings, or copy-on-write for literals etc. There are other reasons for strings to be immutable.

Comment: It is a design choice for the sake of safety: if I hold a reference to a ```java.lang.String``` object I'm sure no other process will alter its contents.

Comment: Should I post every reason for this answer. I posted what I know as an answer. And I believe I posted a correct answer for his/her question. @JonSkeet

Comment: As I said before, it would be entirely reasonable for Java have been designed a different way - being able to pool literals is one efficiency benefit of using immutable strings, but if immutability was a generally bad idea for strings, we just wouldn't do that. There are *much* better reasons for strings being immutable.